# Nuxt3 wrong computed reactivity client/server for tag's attributes

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

Reproduction:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-t4dmdk?file=app.vue

Same computed. Returned string depends on client/server. Wrong string for div's id.

[div's content is 'valueFromClient' but id is 'valueFromServer'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEDcP.png)

Why is div content correct 'valueFromClient' but attribute(id) is 'valueFromServer'?

The original problem:

I am using state manager(pinia), part of the code was executed on the server side (process.server was checked) and part of the code on the client side (process.client was checked) for SSR purposes. When changes occurred in the client side, DOM elements remained with the old values from the server. I checked computed, they triggered on the client and returned the correct client values, but these client values were not substituted into the attributes of DOM elements.